# Invoke event handler on a different form after closing the active form

Tags: c#, formclosing, active-form

I have a C# application in which I need specific or a function to execute on a form after closing the active form.

The form in which I need the code to excute becomes the active form after the previous active form is closed. So in a nutshell after closing this form the form in which I need the event handler or function to run will then become the active form. Is there a way that this is possible?

I have tried the Form_Enter event handler on the form that becomes active after the other form is closed, but that did not work.

Comment: It is unclear why you think you need to help.  Windows already goes looking for another window in an application to give the focus to when your active window closes.  Since there is only one to choose from, that window underneath the active window automatically gets activated.  You'd otherwise do this explicitly by subscribing the FormClosing event and call the Activate() method.

Comment: I did.  I tried entering the code that I wanted executed on the Form_Enter event handler of the form that becomes the active form after the first form is closed.

Comment: I know that Hans, but I need a specific code to execute on the form that becomes activated after the previous active form is closed.

Comment: @user1546315 I think your approach might be wrong, what are you trying to do, be a little more general.

Comment: I have edited the question.  I feel my original wording of the issue was poor.

Comment: If you need to run "specific code" then simply subscribing the FormClosed event should suffice.  Some odds that you ought to use ShowDialog() instead so you can write that "specific code" after the ShowDialog call.

Comment: It would be a good idea to paste the code where you close from1 and open form2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve what you are trying to do more simply. The code you use to show Form2 from Form1 (Main), you can add your code there like so:

```
Class Form1 {
    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Form2  newForm = Form2();
        newForm.ShowDialog(); // To prevent the main form carry on
        // Your code needed to be excuted
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the form closing event set the DialogResult as follows:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes;
}
```

When you open the form look for the response as follows:

```
if (Form1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    ////do stuff.
}
```

I hope this helps.